# Unexpected Value in MUI DatePicker Input Field When Testing with Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

**Background:**
I am working on a test for a React application that uses Material-UI's `DesktopDatePicker` component. I'm using Cypress for end-to-end testing. The test involves selecting a date from the `DesktopDatePicker`, but I'm encountering an issue where the value of the input field matches the expected date format after a date selection, but cypress still throws an error.

**Cypress Issue:**
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<input#:r3:.MuiInputBase-input.MuiOutlinedInput-input.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd.css-nxo287-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input>' to have attribute 'value' with the value '15 / 12 / 2023', but the value was '⁦⁨15⁩ / ⁨12⁩ / ⁨2023⁩⁩'.

**Code Snippet:**
Here's the relevant part of the Cypress test:

```
  it("allows the user to select the Leave Start date in the MUI DatePicker", () => {
    // Open the DatePicker
    cy.get("[data-testid='CalendarIcon']").first().click();

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0, December is 11

    cy.get(".MuiPickersDay-root").contains("15").click();

    cy.get("[data-testid='CalendarIcon']").first().parent().parent().parent().find("input").should("have.attr", "value", `15 / ${currentMonth} / ${currentYear}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare both values that you posted on the error log and apparently they are different. The left value is indeed `'15 / 12 / 2023'`, but the right one is actually `'[U+2066][U+2068]15[U+2069] / [U+2068]12[U+2069] / [U+2068]2023[U+2069][U+2069]'`. So there are some hidden unicode characters in the value that makes it look equal as the value expected even though it isn't.

Try checking how the library used it handling the format and if you can customize it. If not, you could try to extract the value, format it and then compare it to the value you expect.

Something like that:

```js
cy.get("[data-testid='CalendarIcon']").then(el => {
    const value = ... somehow get the value from `el` here ...
    const treatedValue = ... treat the value to get rid of the unicode characters ...
    expect(treatedValue).to.equal(expectedValue);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

To complete the test, I wrote this code:

```
  it("allows the user to select the Leave Start date in the MUI DatePicker", () => {
    // Open the DatePicker
    cy.get("[data-testid='CalendarIcon']").first().click();

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0, December is 11

    cy.get(".MuiPickersDay-root").contains("15").click();

    // Use a more permissive RegExp
    const expectedDateRegex = new RegExp(`15.*${currentMonth}.*${currentYear}`);

    cy.get("[data-testid='CalendarIcon']")
      .first()
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .find("input")
      .invoke("val")
      .then((val) => {
        cy.log("Actual value: " + val); // Debug: Log the actual value
        expect(val).to.match(expectedDateRegex);
      });
  });
```